# How do I query and make sure that the value returned is only added to an array once?

Tags: ios, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I have a code which runs thru all the child of `palettes` and finds out if a color hex matches any of the values in those child. If there's a match, it will then extract the URL out of the `childByAutoID` and then add it to an array.

```
databaseRef.child("palettes").queryOrdered(byChild: "top").queryEqual(toValue: text).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

                for each in snapDict as [String:AnyObject]{

                    let _URL = each.value["URL"] as! String
                    self.arrayVar.append(_URL) // Turning it into an array.

                }
            }
    })

        databaseRef.child("palettes").queryOrdered(byChild: "bottom").queryEqual(toValue: text).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

                for each in snapDict as [String:AnyObject]{

                    let _URL = each.value["URL"] as! String
                    self.arrayVar.append(_URL) // Turning it into an array.

                }
            }

        })

        databaseRef.child("palettes").queryOrdered(byChild: "accessories").queryEqual(toValue: text).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

                for each in snapDict as [String:AnyObject]{

                    let _URL = each.value["URL"] as! String
                    self.arrayVar.append(_URL) // Turning it into an array.

                }
            }

        })

        databaseRef.child("palettes").queryOrdered(byChild: "shoes").queryEqual(toValue: text).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

                for each in snapDict as [String:AnyObject]{

                    let _URL = each.value["URL"] as! String
                    self.arrayVar.append(_URL) // Turning it into an array.

                }
            }
        })
    }
```

However, the problem with this is that when there are two similar values inside the same `childByAutoID`, it will append the 'URL' twice.

Here's an example of my JSON tree:

```
{
  "palettes" : {
    "-KTjfdgcwdkF5j3OWOg8" : {
      "URL" : "test1",
      "accessories" : "#000000",
      "bottom" : "#2B676E",
      "shoes" : "#000000",
      "top" : "#274E64"
    },
    "-KTji_7xUNu2PejD4Xz6" : {
      "URL" : "test2",
      "accessories" : "#2B6766",
      "bottom" : "#2B676E",
      "shoes" : "#000000",
      "top" : "#274E64"
    }
  }
}
```

Which will return `[test1, test1, test2]` when `#000000` is equal to `text` and when `arrayVar` is printed.

How do I ensure that the URL is only appended once per `childByAutoID`? For example, `[test1, test2]` in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your array to a mutable dictionary and then set your objects that you retrieve as key and their value boolean:-

```
var arrayVar = NSMutableDictionary()
databaseRef.child("palettes").queryOrdered(byChild: "shoes").queryEqual(toValue: text).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            for each in snapDict as [String:AnyObject]{

                let _URL = each.value["URL"] as! String
                self.arrayVar.setObject(true, forKey: _URL as NSCopying)
            }
        }
    })
```

To get your URL's just :-

```
 for eachUrl in arrayVar{

      let url = eachUrl.key

     }
```

Navigating through Dictionaries is much more efficient and relational than array, specially in firebase.

Comment: Oh the reason why I needed it to be in an array form is because I need to use it to populate a collectionsview. So these URLs will be translated into images to form an array of images before displaying in a collectionsView

Comment: Answer Updated ... You can easily navigate through the dictionary to do so. As iterating through an entire array and checking for the required value , if it already exist's is waste of memory

Comment: Thanks, but I've taken to another method by restructuring my json tree. Figured my current model was way too messy.